# Compare ticks to date time (5 mins from now)

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net

I have a DateTime in Ticks. I want to know the best way to compare this and return false if the ticks greater then 5 minutes for now and return true if not.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
if( new DateTime(ticks) > DateTime.Now.AddMinutes(5))
   return false;
else return true;
```

Answer (score 3):

```
return ticks <= DateTime.Now.AddMinutes(5).Ticks;
```